# Executing a background process that can be cancelled with Windows Form button

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, pass-by-reference

I need to launch a background process (Solver) which receives data from my main form (Form1) and indicates its progress in ProgressBar in new form (FormStatus). I decided to launch the FormStatus from Form1 and then OnLoad of FormStatus to execute the Solver process in a separate Thread. At any time of Solver execution I may abort it with ButtonStop in FormStatus. If launched directly, the process blocks the form.

If process is terminated with button, an exception is thrown, otherwise (if calculation is complete) Solver returns null string and closes the FormStatus.

Code for main Form1:

```cs
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CS_Threads
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        // Contains some data
        public class CData
        { public int Int { set; get; } }

        private CData data;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            data = new CData() { Int = 100 };
        }

        // On ButtonGO press open FormStatus to start the solver
        private void ButtonGO_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int result;

            using (FormStatus f = new FormStatus(data))
            {
                f.ShowDialog();
                result = f.Result;
            }

            // Fill the RTBox according to calculation results
            if (result < 0) RTBox.Text = "Failed";
            else RTBox.Text = "Success";
        }
    }
}
```

Code for FormStatus:

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CS_Threads
{
    public partial class FormStatus : Form
    {
        private Form1.CData data;
        private CancellationTokenSource source;

        public int Result { private set; get; }

        public FormStatus(Form1.CData d)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            data = d; // Didn't find a better way to pass the class reference. Maybe make this member public in Form1?
            Result = -1; // Default value of Result if form was closed or process terminated
            source = new CancellationTokenSource();
        }

        // On ButtonStop press stop the Solver and close form
        private void ButtonStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            source.Cancel();
            Close();
        }

        // On form load launch Solver: Warning CS1998 This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously.Consider using the 'await' operator...
        private async void FormStatus_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Task<string> t = Task.Run(() => Solver(data, this, source.Token));
            string res = t.Result;
        }

        // Solver: Same warning CS1998
        private static async Task<string> Solver(Form1.CData data, FormStatus f, CancellationToken ct)
        {
            try
            {
                // Do some calculations
                long max = 1000;
                for (long i = 0; i < max && !ct.IsCancellationRequested; i++)
                    for (long j = 0; j < max && !ct.IsCancellationRequested; j++)
                    {
                        data.Int = 10;
                        f.ProgressBar.Value = (int)(((double)i / (double)max) * ((double)j / (double)max) * 100.0);
                    }

                if (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    f.Result = 0;
                    f.Close();
                }
                else throw new Exception("Task has been cancelled");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { return ex.ToString(); }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

For now I have two warnings in FormStatus and the process terminates on first iterations of Solver, throwing an exception in 'string res': System.InvalidOperationException: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'ProgressBar' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

I've just started to work with threads, so there may be some really stupid stuff...

Comment: You need to call Invoke on a main thread object like the Form itself from your background thread.  That will enqueue the action on the main thread's message loop and perform it in order along with other messages.

Comment: You're blocking the UI... Invoke the progressbar as you're not on the UI thread anymore.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.progress-1?view=netframework-4.8